# Google Apps Marketplace app installation callback

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We've migrated our app from the old marketplace to the new one. After a few days we've received an email that we don't comply with an SSO policy - the user is not recognized after he installs the application.

In the old app we had a specific setup link, that was opened for the user after he installed the app - thus making him recognizable. Is there such a function in the market? Is there some sort of a callback for the installation event in the new marketplace?

P.S. the guy from Google told me to post technical questions on Stackoverflow and that "Our developer relations team monitors that forum and will be able to assist you."

**EDIT**:
There's the *Additional app setup* link in this after-installation popup (which clearly no user will click):

[image: post-installation popup]

Is there a way to call the URL that of the *Additional app setup* in the background, without needing the user to click an obscure link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was an intentional design change which is different than how it used to work in v1 of the marketplace.

If you need interactive setup, best thing to do is put in a check on login to see if the domain has been configured. You can use the licensing API to check for a marketplace install record or directory API to check user permissions if those matter for your use case.

If you just need to run a background task, you can periodically poll the licensing API to detect new installations of the app. This shouldn't be done too often, so if you need to do things *before* a user logs you're still better off going with a check on login to route them to the setup flow as needed.

Comment: That's what we ended up doing. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to determine if the domain for a user installing our app already has the app installed.  Is this the licensing API you're referring to? https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/index.  If so, it looks like it requires a product/sku id. What did you guys end up using for these values?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same thing here - how did you get this to work?  I assume you used one of the Google Apps Marketplace License endpoints, such as [UserLicense:get](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/userLicense/get)?  

I'm using PHP and unfortunately the PHP client currently doesn't support this API, but I can't even get the example to work when I try it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/userLicense/get#try-it). What do you send for applicationId and userId?