# Why does Test Install Flow ignore Setup URL and instead uses Universal Navigation Link

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We're trying to set up a new marketplace app. As suggested by the Google Apps setup UI, we have provided a  Setup URL for setting up an account with the service.

However, if I click on the Test Install Flow button, it redirects to the Universal Navigation link instead of the dedicated application Setup url.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup URL is never invoked by Google. I don't know why, and I don't know why they provide a field for it.

An answer I got from a Google guy is that if you need an interactive setup you should just implement it in your Universal Navigation link (on the first time the admin opens it or something). The full answer is here: [Google Apps Marketplace app installation callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506235/google-apps-marketplace-app-installation-callback)