# Google Apps Marketplace multiple domains(app installations)

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We migrating our app from the old Marketplace to the new one. And we faced with the problem like described here - [Google Apps Marketplace app installation callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506235/google-apps-marketplace-app-installation-callback)

But we have special app architecture, it allows to the same user authorize multiple domains. For example we have user(authorized with google +) admin@tester1.com and he needs to install app for following domains:

- tester1.com where admin account is admin@tester1.com
- tester2.com where admin account is admin@tester2.com

For tester1.com we can use licensing API and check if app is installed and who installed it. We already have authorized account admin@tester1.com and the same user installed app.
No issues for this scenario.

Next user needs to install app for tester2.com. In process of installation(at the marketplace side) user switching to new account admin@tester2.com and installing app. 
When user backs to us, we using licensing API again and check if app is installed and who installed it. At this step app will be installed, but it will be installed by user admin@tester2.com which is currently not connected to our app.

For this scenario, how we can securely recognize that domain tester2.com should be linked to user admin@tester1.com? Any recommendations/advices?

Currently we see only one way - require user to authorize admin account for each domain that he wants to install with our app.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a special case, and Google don't have any guidelines around how to handle it. Deciding how to charge for and provision your application is left up to the developer.